# How to pass list of column names to Plotly px.scatter

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to pass a variable to the 'y' parameter that is a list of pandas column names to Plotly Express px.scatter function. I can get this to work with a Plotly go figure, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong with the Plotly Express, so it's easier to use the 'color' by group feature.

Plotly Go code (works):

```
fig = go.Figure()
    for name in y_name:
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['X'],
                                 y=dff[name],
                                 mode='markers',
                                 name=name))
        fig.update_xaxes(title='X')
        fig.update_yaxes(title=name)
```

Plotly Express code (doesn't work):

```
    fig = px.scatter(dff,
                     x=dff['X'],
                     y=dff[y_name],
                     color=dff['Frame'])
    fig.update_xaxes(title='X')
    fig.update_yaxes(title=y_name)
```

I would have X (length of list) of traces on the same plot.

Comment: Have you tried passing the column values instead of a column (for example, `x = dff['X'].values`)

Comment: Tried your suggestion. I get the following error message.
ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to pass as values? Normally I'd expect xs and ys to be values (numbers). I'm not familiar with this idea of passing a list of column names.

Comment: plotly.express is designed to set axes and colors using only column names by specifying data frames. Furthermore, both numeric and categorical variables can be specified for colors. Since column names and lists can be specified for axes, express can also specify them in the following ways. `fig = px.scatter(dff,x=dff['X'].tolist(),y=dff[y_name].tolist(),color=dff['Frame'])`